# How to change style under div with onclick on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've searched for similar question for quite a long time but all my searches gone in vain. Here is my code

```
<div class="footer-sidebar container" style="height:40px;"></div>
<button class="button">Click</button>
```

Now if someone clicks on button then my `.container` height should increase to 400px and if someone clicks on the same button it must back to 40px.

**Edit: (Added CSS)**

```
.footer-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1500;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do that by adding a class to your div like this:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    $('.container').toggleClass('open');
}
```

Inline styles for this should be avoided. Use your css file and add something like this to it:

```
.container {
    height: 40px;
}

.container.open {
    height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript version

#### (opposed to the previously added `JQuery` option):

Using `booleans` (tested):

```
var fullSize = false; // Used for toggling
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0]; // Get button
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("footer-sidebar")[0]; // Get div

button.onclick = function() { 
  if(fullSize) { div.style.bottom = 0 + "px"; fullSize = false; } // If div is already 400px...
  else { div.style.bottom = -360 + "px"; fullSize = true; } // If div is already 40px...
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6ez6q51/1/)

---

Using `classes` (untested):

**CSS**:

```
.open {
  height: 400px;
}

.closed {
  height: 40px;
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button"); // Get button
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("footer-sidebar container")[0]; // Get div

button.onclick = function() {
  if(div.className = "closed") { div.className = "open" }
  else if(div.className = "open") { div.className = "closed" }
  else { div.className = "open" }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please take a look at the edited version of my question. This is what the css to footer-sidebar and your or anyone's answer is not working. I hope you people are giving excellent solution but perhaps my given css is stopping that code to work?

Comment: Ok, I'll build a JSFiddle.